# $n-$square root as an exponential

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

If I have for example

$$g(x)=\sqrt[n]{f(x)} \tag 1$$

where it is defined when $f(x)\geq 0$ if $n=2k$, with $k\in \Bbb N$ and if $n=2k+1$ the $\operatorname{dom} g(x)\equiv \operatorname{dom} f(x)$, is it true that

$$\sqrt[3]{f(x)}=\exp(\ln(f(x))/3), \quad ?$$

and in general

$$\sqrt[n]{f(x)}=\exp(\ln(f(x))/n), \quad ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that:

$$\ln(x^a) = a\ln(x),$$

for $x > 0$.

Take the logarithm of $\sqrt[n]{f(x)}$:

$$\ln\left(\sqrt[n]{f(x)}\right)=\ln\left[\left(f(x)\right)^\frac{1}{n}\right] = \frac{1}{n}\ln(f(x)).$$

Now, apply the exponential to both sides:

$$\exp\left(\ln\left(\sqrt[n]{f(x)}\right)\right) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\ln(f(x))\right) \Rightarrow$$

$$\sqrt[n]{f(x)}= \exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\ln(f(x))\right).$$

Of course, $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in its domain.

Comment: Grazieeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee :-)......for your answer and for the kindness.

Comment: But this only works for $f(x)>0$.

Comment: @Sebastiano Prego :D

Comment: @JensSchwaiger thanks for the remark. I add it to the post.